# What is the longest string that can be stored using firebase?

Tags: firebase

Whats the max number of characters in a string I can save in firebase?
Is it unlimited?
At what point will It get too slow?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Per the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#data_tree), the maximum size of a child value is **10mb** (UTF-8 encoded).

UTF-8 uses 1 to 4 bytes per character, so a 10mb string could contain between 2.5 million - 10 million characters.

Comment: Are this still valid?

Comment: Is there a way to increase it from 10mb upwards ?

Comment: It seems still valid as of 2021

Comment: 10mb per document is still valid for Realtime Database. For those using Firestore, is 1mb. Quoting [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55956609/10046781), 
"Large amounts of content that don't need to indexed for querying are usually better stored in a product such as Cloud Storage rather than Cloud Firestore".