# What is the longest string value that can be store in a firestore document field?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a long text of String that I want to store in a firestore document field. I know that each document has a limit of 1mb of size. Does that mean my string will only be as long as 1mb in size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you have a single string field in a document, it will be limited to the maximum size of a document.

Large amounts of content that don't need to indexed for querying are usually better stored in a product such as Cloud Storage rather than Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Wow I hadn't thought of that, I mostly store images, videos or pdfs only. Thanks Doug! and also I am grateful for your explanation on cloud functions which helped me a lot in handling changes in my database. 