# Storing HTML in NOSQL Database?

Tags: javascript, html, nosql

Is it safe/possible to store HTML pages in a NoSQL database like firebase for a page builder that users can edit?

I want to store the whole HTML content (not including) js and HTML/BODY tags in as a sting in firebase. Which users can load to a client-side editor and edit.

Storing just the values of the content might be hard since the page content can change drastically.

The idea is the user, edits a base template, that template plus the new changes can be saved to a NoSQL database (firebase) the user can then edit the saved content again later or download it (once scripts, assets, and HTML tags are added back in.)

Probably not the best way but within my skill set to do.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you'll want to check if your database / provider has any limits on the maximum write size.

Comment: any cache-to-db works similarly, so it is safe and possible. As @jspcal mentioned, size could be a problem; cache-to-file is an alternative

Comment: Seems the size is fine if I'm understanding this correctly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531500/whats-the-longest-string-i-can-save-and-get-using-firebase

Comment: 10MB confirmed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits

Comment: Yes, with one caveat for Firebase Realtime DB: *Write operations larger than 1MB succeed on the database, but they don't trigger a function invocation* (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits)

Comment: @jspcal ah true but 500 pages of text is equal one megabyte so I think I'm safe, none of the html will be anywhere near that

Comment: The Google News home page is over a MB. An HTML page can easily exceed 1 MB. But if you're not triggering functions, that limit won't be an issue.